Show, by example, that for fixed nonzero elements a and b in a ring, the equation ax = b can have more than one solution.
I have come up with the $Z_6$. For the elements in the table below there is more than one solution for the equation ax = b., for example, a=2, b=4, then for x=2,5 this equation has a solution.
I want to find a non-trivial solution for this in terms of matrix or Z mod n.
$
\
\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
\cdot & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\
3 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 3 \\
4 & 0 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 4 & 2 \\
5 & 0 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\
$

Consider the ring $\mathbb Z_6$
Note that this ring has zero divisors —- i.e.  $2\cdot 3 = 0$
So, $2z = 0$ has solutions $z=0$ and $z=3$
Exploiting zero divisors, you should have no problem generating more examples.
